# How do I properly reload data into a table from the local datastore after unpinning an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, local-datastore

In the iOS app I'm developing I have a `UITableView` that is populated with objects from the local datastore (I subclassed `PFTableViewController` for this). I have it set up so that the object is unpinned when the delete button is tapped for that particular row, but after the button is tapped the object is still showing up in the table. The only way to make it disappear is to pull down to refresh or hit the back button and then come back to this view.

I've tried calling `[tableview reloadData]` and `[self loadObjects]` to try to get the `UITableView` to refresh but it doesn't work. I've also tried 
`[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]` but this just causes an error saying there's an "invalid number of rows in section 0."

How can I set it up so that the delete button causes the app to unpin the object and delete the row/refresh the data so that the object won't appear in the table anymore? Thanks. Here's the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.objects count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        NSInteger row = [tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow row];
        PFObject *delProfessor = [self.objects objectAtIndex:row];
        [delProfessor unpinInBackground];

        //These are the three ideas I've tried so far
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[tableView reloadData];
        //[self loadObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` you need to update the data source used by the table view to reflect the row about to be deleted.

Comment: I thought the unpinInBackground is updating the data source. Is there some other line of code I'm missing?

Comment: Look at your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Is the value returned there properly updated by the call to `unpinInBackground`? Perhaps you should post your `numberOfRowsInSection` method in your question.

Comment: Just added the `numberOfRowsInSection` method to my question. I actually had it commented out before but it's not helping out either way at the moment. How can I go about updating the `numberOfRowsInSection` method by the call to `unPinInBackground`?

Comment: You need to remove the object from `self.objects`, then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: In the declaration for objects, it is listed as being readonly. Can I still remove the object in this case? Also, when I start typing in Xcode autocomplete starts listing out methods that start with `removeObserver: (NSObject *)`. Is this the right type of method?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove object from datasource your self.objects array

`[self.objects removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
 [self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: In the declaration for `objects`, it is listed as being readonly. Can I still remove the object in this case? Also, when I start typing in Xcode autocomplete starts listing out methods that start with `removeObserver: (NSObject *)`, not `removeObjectAtIndex`. Is this the right type of method?

Comment: your array is NSMutable?